# Is it possible to setup a root like user for global read only access?

Tags: security

I'm hoping to give a security scanner a user that can read everything but not change or execute anything.  Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: What do you want them to be able to read that a normal user can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be the easiest or best way, but you could:

- Make the user a part of the disks group *isn't required, but seems like the right thing to do*
- Chroot to an HFS+ partition *required because linux filesystems don't support different permissions on links*
- Link the raw disk */dev/sda or whatever* in to the chroot with read only permissions
- Bootstrap your code from there.

I'm not aware of an OOTB way to do what you're asking.

Comment: This seems like a pretty cool concept.

Comment: I don't like saying "No.  You can't do that at all."  I'ld rather say "These are the hard parts, and how I would conceptually work around them... but I can't dev that part in a time that is reasonable with everything else I am doing."

Comment: My only other idea was using apparmour but from the last talk I attended about this mentioned that a fair amount of the documentation is documenting theoretical / planned features.

Comment: It's the simplest way I could think of to make it happen.  You COULD make it happen that way.  You'ld need to plan to handle mapped drives for LUKS or whatever, but it is doable.